# How can I resolve cyclic linker dependencies in Visual Studio (c++)?

Tags: visual-c++

I am sitting here in front of a huge legacy project with hundreds of DLLs that partly reference each other via Libs (also implicitly over several Libs). So changing the design is not possible. Currently, the whole thing is solved like this: there are already old Libs, and therefore new ones can be built ...

In my search for solutions, I came across .exp files, but I couldn’t find anywhere a guide on how to integrate this into Visual Studio specifically. But I am also grateful for other suggestions for solutions.

Comment: See if this helps: [Mutual Imports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/mutual-imports)

Comment: No, that does not help since it does not explain how to integrete that LIB command into Visual Studio.